# do loop not executing correctly

Tags: c, do-while

I have a function readin() reads a number of persons’ names and their corresponding telephone
numbers and returns the number of names that have entered. The character '#' is used to indicate the end of user input.

```
int readin(Employee *emp)
{
    int i=0,j;
    do { // loop statements to be executed no matter what
        printf("Enter name:\n");
        scanf("%s",emp->name); // stores name inside structure array
        j = (strcmp(emp->name,"#") != 0); // returns 1 if name not equals to #

    } while(j);{ // while name is not equals to # , execute code below and loop back 'do'
            printf("Enter tel:\n");
            scanf("%s",emp->telno);

            emp++;
            i++;
    }
    return i;
}
```

Intended results should be:

```
Enter name:
John
Enter tel:
12345678
Enter name:
#
```

Results obtained:

```
Enter name:
John
Enter name:
#
Enter tel:
```

When j = 1, the while loop does not run but it loops back to the do portion instead of exiting the loop completely.
When j = 0, the codes in the while loop are executed for some reason. Please advise.

Comment: The indentation or line-splitting (or absence thereof) on `} while(j);{ ` is worrying.  The `do { … } while (j);` loop ends at the semicolon.  The `{` is an independent compound statement unrelated to the `do`-`while` loop.  The `do`-`while` will repeatedly enter the employee name until you overwrite it with `#` (whereupon the loop will end, but the previous entries have been lost — the name is `"#"`).  Then the telephone number is entered once

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Understood. It seems that I had a misconception regarding the do loop.

Comment: I missed the `emp++` which steps through the array passed as an argument.  So, you can get multiple employees entered — that part was my mistake for not reading the code carefully enough.  You should have an argument that tells the function how big the array is so that you can avoid overflow.

Comment: What happens when `#` is entered as a telephone number? What happens when you have EOF?

Answer (score 1):

you know that is how exactly do while work look

```
do{
 state1;
}
while(statement);

rest of code;
```

if statement is true, 
it will goes to state part and does it again and when statement is wrong it goes to rest of your code.

which in your case while string!='#' you will always enter do while() loop and when statement is wrong or `j==0` you will exit do while loop

I recommend this:

```
int readin(Employee* emp)
{
    int i = 0, j =0;
    while (1)
    {
        printf("Enter name:\n");
        scanf("%s", &emp->name);
        if((strcmp(emp->name, "#") == 0))
                    break;

        printf("Enter tel:\n");
        scanf("%s", &emp->telno);

        emp++;
        i++;
    }

    return i;
}
```

Comment: I think the code could survive without the variable `j` and simply testing `if (strcmp(emp->name, "#") == 0) break;`.  You have also inverted the logic, I think — the input should stop when the user types `#`, shouldn't it?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler you'right `j` is not necessary.I just didn't want to change loop too much. and  sorry I meant `if(!j)` this.

Answer (score 0):

Using `scanf` for line-oriented input is the *wrong* choice. The recommended way to read lines of user input is with `fgets()` or POSIX `getline()`.

**Why use fgets()?**

In short, it is more robust, it handles internal whitespace allowing you to enter `"first last"` name or `"(409) 555-1212"` as the telno (`scanf()` with `"%s"` can't), and your only responsibility is to validate the return and then trim the trailing `'\n'` from the input. You validate the return to handle a manually generated `EOF` where the user cancels input by pressing <kbd>Ctrl+d</kbd> on Linux or <kbd>Ctrl+z</kbd> on windows. (just as you must also do for `scanf()`) As a benefit, you don't need to enter `'#'` to end input because `fgets()` reads `'\n'` when <kbd>Enter</kbd> alone is pressed allowing your user to simply press <kbd>Enter</kbd> on an empty `name` line to exit.

For example, you can read and validate that both a name and telephone number string has been entered with something as simple as:

```
#define MAXTEL  32      /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */
#define MAXNM   64
#define MAXEMP 128

typedef struct {
    char name[MAXNM],
        telno[MAXTEL];
} employee;

int readin (employee *emp)
{
    int n;

    for (n = 0; n < MAXEMP; n++) {  /* loop continually - protect array bounds */
        fputs ("\nEnter name: ", stdout);   /* prompt */
        /* read/validate, check for Enter alone to exit */
        if (!fgets (emp[n].name, MAXNM, stdin) || *emp[n].name == '\n')
            break;
        emp[n].name[strcspn(emp[n].name, "\n")] = 0;    /* trim trailing \n */

        fputs ("Enter tel : ", stdout);                 /* prompt */
        if (!fgets (emp[n].telno, MAXTEL, stdin))       /* read/validate */
            break;
        emp[n].telno[strcspn(emp[n].telno, "\n")] = 0;  /* trim trailing \n */
    }

    return n;
}
```

**What About Using scanf()?**

It is doable, but your responsibilities increase dramatically as you will need to remove the `'\n'` that remains in `stdin` after taking input to ensure the next input in your code after leaving the `readin()` function doesn't fail. With `scanf()` (set up to loop as you indicate requiring a `'#'` to terminate input) would require:

```
int readin (employee *emp)
{
    int n;

    for (n = 0; n < MAXEMP; n++) {  /* loop continually - protect array bounds */
        int rtn;            /* variable to save the return of scanf */

        fputs ("\nEnter name: ", stdout);       /* prompt */
        rtn = scanf(" %63[^\n]", emp->name);    /* read into tmp saving return */

        if (rtn == EOF) {   /* handle EOF - user presses Ctrl+d (Ctrl+z win) */
            fputs ("(user canceled input)\n", stderr);
            break;
        }
        else if (rtn == 1 && *emp->name == '#') /* good input and '#' -- bail */
            break;

        for (;;) {  /* loop contianually until valid telno entered */

            fputs ("Enter tel : ", stdout);         /* prompt */
            rtn = scanf(" %31[^\n]", emp->telno);   /* read saving return */

            if (rtn == EOF) {       /* handle EOF - ditto */
                fputs ("(user canceled input)\n", stderr);
                break;
            }
            else if (rtn == 1) {    /* good input */
                /* further validate telno here */
                break;
            }
        }   /* empty trailing \n from stdin */
        for (int c = getchar(); c != '\n' && c != EOF; c = getchar()) {}

        emp++;  /* advance pointer */
    }

    return n;   /* return success */
}
```

And you are still left having to enter a `'#'` to terminate input -- which should not be necessary.

*Which would you rather use?*

**Example**

Use either function with:

```
int main (void) {

    employee e[MAXEMP] = {{ .name = "" }};
    int n = readin (e);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf ("\nemployee:\n  name  : %s\n  telno : %s\n", 
                e[i].name, e[i].telno);
}
```

**Example Use/Output - fgets()**

```
$ ./bin/empnametelnoarray

Enter name: John Q. Public
Enter tel : 444-1212

Enter name: Sally P. Public
Enter tel : 444-1222

Enter name: Mary Jane
Enter tel : 444-1223

Enter name:

employee:
  name  : John Q. Public
  telno : 444-1212

employee:
  name  : Sally P. Public
  telno : 444-1222

employee:
  name  : Mary Jane
  telno : 444-1223
```

**Example Use/Output - scanf()**

```
$ ./bin/empnametelnoarray

Enter name: John Q. Public
Enter tel : 444-1212

Enter name: Sally P. Public
Enter tel : 444-1222

Enter name: Mary Jane
Enter tel : 444-1223

Enter name: #

employee:
  name  : John Q. Public
  telno : 444-1212

employee:
  name  : Sally P. Public
  telno : 444-1222

employee:
  name  : Mary Jane
  telno : 444-1223
```

The complete example is shown below, just add `-DUSESCANF` to your compile string (or `/D USESCANF` for VS) to use the `scanf()` version, the default is to use `fgets()`. On balance, there is no reason to use `scanf()` to read two strings of user input. You are far better served using a *line-oriented* input function to read lines of input from the user:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXTEL  32      /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */
#define MAXNM   64
#define MAXEMP 128

typedef struct {
    char name[MAXNM],
        telno[MAXTEL];
} employee;

#ifndef USESCANF
int readin (employee *emp)
{
    int n;

    for (n = 0; n < MAXEMP; n++) {  /* loop continually - protect array bounds */
        fputs ("\nEnter name: ", stdout);   /* prompt */
        /* read/validate, check for Enter alone to exit */
        if (!fgets (emp[n].name, MAXNM, stdin) || *emp[n].name == '\n')
            break;
        emp[n].name[strcspn(emp[n].name, "\n")] = 0;    /* trim trailing \n */

        fputs ("Enter tel : ", stdout);                 /* prompt */
        if (!fgets (emp[n].telno, MAXTEL, stdin))       /* read/validate */
            break;
        emp[n].telno[strcspn(emp[n].telno, "\n")] = 0;  /* trim trailing \n */
    }

    return n;
}
#else
int readin (employee *emp)
{
    int n;

    for (n = 0; n < MAXEMP; n++) {  /* loop continually - protect array bounds */
        int rtn;            /* variable to save the return of scanf */

        fputs ("\nEnter name: ", stdout);       /* prompt */
        rtn = scanf(" %63[^\n]", emp->name);    /* read into tmp saving return */

        if (rtn == EOF) {   /* handle EOF - user presses Ctrl+d (Ctrl+z win) */
            fputs ("(user canceled input)\n", stderr);
            break;
        }
        else if (rtn == 1 && *emp->name == '#') /* good input and '#' -- bail */
            break;

        for (;;) {  /* loop contianually until valid telno entered */

            fputs ("Enter tel : ", stdout);         /* prompt */
            rtn = scanf(" %31[^\n]", emp->telno);   /* read saving return */

            if (rtn == EOF) {       /* handle EOF - ditto */
                fputs ("(user canceled input)\n", stderr);
                break;
            }
            else if (rtn == 1) {    /* good input */
                /* further validate telno here */
                break;
            }
        }   /* empty trailing \n from stdin */
        for (int c = getchar(); c != '\n' && c != EOF; c = getchar()) {}

        emp++;  /* advance pointer */
    }

    return n;   /* return success */
}
#endif

int main (void) {

    employee e[MAXEMP] = {{ .name = "" }};
    int n = readin (e);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf ("\nemployee:\n  name  : %s\n  telno : %s\n", 
                e[i].name, e[i].telno);
}
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.